# Set frontend session time out limit in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to set session timeout limit for frontend users in joomla 2.5? I had set the Session Lifetime option in Global configuration but it sets the limit in backend only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can comment the line `JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');` on top in the file
modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php

After that the time from the backend will also expires the frontend as well as backend

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin. According to my knowledge.

If you are to

> Session Control Plugin make the different session lifetime for
>   different user group on your Joomla site. Session Control Plugin make
>   the user group online all the time on your Joomla site.

[Session Control Plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/13982)

[Session Keeper](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/21489)

Other option

> Go to Site -> Global configuration -> System tab and set the Session
>   Lifetime

Comment: Session Control Plugin is compatible joomla 1.5 only

Comment: Session Keeper is mine, and I keep it compatible with both the current LTS and STS Joomla releases (currently 2.5 and 3.x respectively)

Answer (score 0):

From my tests I have the opinion that the value you set in back-end (Global Configuration > System > Session Lifetime) is used for back-end as well as for front-end.

You may want to check that value you are getting in frontend. Use the code below:

> echo "Session will expire in " . JFactory::getSession()->getExpire() / 60 . " min.";

It looks to me that JFactory is responsible with setting the expiration time. It uses the config time or if absent it uses 900 seconds (15 minutes).

Comment: Yes, Im getting the session limit in frontend, but it is not affecting the frontend