# Joomla 2.5 database user session

Tags: php, session, joomla2.5

where joomla 2.5 cheks users session timeout? I want to change this script. in configuraion.php lifetime param not works. I changed this param from 15 min to 120 min but nothing changed . user timeout is still 15 min.

Comment: Try to restart your apache after making this change.

Comment: I restarted apache web server but it still doesnot works

Comment: I want to find this script in library

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133191/set-frontend-session-time-out-limit-in-joomla

Comment: User Session not works in administrator, administrator timeouted every 3-5 minutes